# php factory pattern design issue

Tags: php

I am learning factory pattern design using php. What my application does is it displays different shapes names such as `Rectangle, Squares etc` and their `x, y` positions. First user will provide x and y values which it will display alongside shape name such as like this `Rectangle(2, 2)`.

The problem with my current code is that it does show shape name i.e. `Rectangle` but it does not show x and y values which user provided. Why and how can I display x and y values?

Below is my code
index.php

```
    include_once("ConcreteCreator.php");
class Client {
    public function __construct() {
        $shapeNow = new ConcreteCreator();
        $display  = $shapeNow->factoryMethod(new Rectangle(2, 2));
        //Above I am passing x and y values in Rectangle(2, 2);
        echo $display . '<br>';
    }    
}

$worker = new Client();
```

Here is ConcreteCreator.php

```
    include_once('Creator.php');
include_once('Rectangle.php');
class ConcreteCreator extends Creator {

    public function factoryMethod(Product $productNow) {
        //echo $productNow;
        $this->createdProduct = new $productNow;
        return $this->createdProduct->provideShape();
    }

}
```

Here is Creator.php

```
abstract class Creator {
    protected $createdProduct;
    abstract public function factoryMethod(Product $productNow);
}
```

Here is Product.php

```
interface Product {
    function provideShape();
}
```

Here is Rectangle.php

```
include_once('Product.php');

class Rectangle implements Product {
    private $x;
    private $y;
            //Here is I am setting users provided x and y values with private vars
    public function __construct($x, $y) {
        echo $x;
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }

    public function provideShape() {
        echo $this->x; //Here x does not show up
        return 'Rectangle (' . $this->x . ', ' . $this->y . ')';
                    //above x and y does not show up.
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you recreating the object in ConcreteCreator.php ? `$this->createdProduct = new $productNow;` just use `$this->createdProduct = $productNow;` and that should fix your problem

Comment: Sorry for deleting comment. From the start. The factory is used to create the more specified instance of the object with the same parent, so lets say you have a figure parent object, it contains some basic functions like getting the x and y, its x and y method and abstract draw method, than you pass the object to the creator with the string lets say "circle" it will fill all the absctract functions with the circle class drawing etc. At least this is how I get the factory pattern.

Comment: This is nothing like the factory pattern. In the example you create the `Rectangle` *yourself*, normally you 'd pass in something like a "rectangle" description and the factory would do the creation.

Comment: @cerkiewny could you please write an example code?

Comment: Yes, basicallt what you want is myrectangle = factory_create(x, y, "rectangle") than factory will read the string, and create object of type rectangle, or will say that this type is not yet supported.

Comment: @cerkiewny I will appreciate if you give me answer here for this by changing my code above. Thank you

Comment: @x4ph4r i hope my answer will do :)

Answer (score 0):

The example use of factory to get you idea of howto do it

```
class Shape{
    int x,y
}

class Rectangle implements Shape{

}

class Circle implements Shape{

}
class ShapeCreator{
    public function create(string shapeName, int x, int y) {
        switch(shapeName)
            rectangle:
                return new Rectangle(x,y)
            circle:
                return new Circle(x,y)
    }    
}
main{
    sc = new ShapeCreator
    Shape circle = sc.create(1,2, "circle")
}
```

to see other conceptions see the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) sometimes the Factory class will just be an interface which will than be implemented by the concrete factories of different type, but if code is simple you can use the case to implement the creation of object.

Comment: I dont like that switch statment you can use for exemple $class = ucfirst(shapeName); if(class_exists($class) return new $class;

Comment: @sidux I think this is not a good idea because we are not sure if "shapeName" is the actuall class that implements the Shape in your case. I have also found a better example of usage of factory [here](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html)

Comment: What is that `circle` in main? And what is `sc`? I think `sc` should `cs` but still don't know what is circle here. You haven't create any instance of circle to use it in main.

Comment: @x4ph4r sc is the factory created to create the specified products, the circle in main is your product created by the factory. Sorry for typo, now all should be clear.

Comment: @cerkiewny u still can use an abstract class for all shapes and teste with instanceOf

Comment: @Sidux this is how everybody do it. You can write your own pattern which will provide construction of infinite class specialized types from what i know the idea is to hardcode all possible types of products, so changing this case to more general approach would be going around the idea of problem that this design pattern solves :) but maybe i got this all wrong.